# How to fix error: "function word_similarity(unknown, text) does not exist" in pg_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I tried using pg_search Trigram search with word_similarity. As per the documentation on [github](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#searching-using-different-search-features) it says that Trigram search requires the trigram extension.

But, what I have done to fix this error is by running `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;` in psql and the return message was 'extension "pg_trgm" already exists'. That means the trigram extension should have been added to my postgres.

However, the error appears with the settings below:

```
include PgSearch::Model
pg_search_scope :search_suggestion,
                 against: %i[title],
                 associated_against: { owner: %i[name legal_name] },
                 using: { tsearch: { dictionary: 'english' }, trigram: { word_similarity: true } },
                 ranked_by: ":trigram"
```

Error message:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function word_similarity(unknown, text) does not exist LINE 1:
...NER JOIN (SELECT "table"."title" AS pg_search_id, (word_simil...
^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm using string as the attribute data type.

Comment: I know nothing about trigram, but the error you're getting is caused by the fact that the first argument to `word_similarity` had `unknown` type. Do you mind including the full SQL query?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I'm not sure I can share the SQL query because I just run this command: `Model.search(keyword)` and the error above was produced.

Comment: @emilas do you mean? `Model.search_suggestion(keyword)` because that is what you are showing in the post.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction. I cannot share the SQL query since I just executed Model.search_suggestion(keyword)

Comment: you can check the extensions available by running `\dx` in psql